# Where to hide the nuke disk

Tags: space-station-13

In space station 13, as the captian of the ship, I'm always handing off the nuke disk to the Head of Security, instructing him to hide it, figuring he's better suited for it than I am.

when there's no Head of Security, I tend to lock it in my secure safe, which usually gets blown up with relative ease.

I've seen people get it implanted into their body, so that if they die, it randomly spawns elsewhere, but that seems unfair to the Ops who have to then seek it out, and if it spawns in space, the station is screwed.

What is the best way to truly keep the disk safe in case of a Nuke Ops round?  Optimally without wasting too much effort in hiding it and shirking your other duties as a captain?

Comment: the space station 13 tag didn't exist yet (And new users can't create it) I've re-tagged the question

Comment: Thank you Xenox. I would've gladly tagged it as such if the tag existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the slightly cheesy solution, which you mentioned, of implanting it into an assistants body cavity works, its not particularly fun for either side.

I prefer putting it into a secure briefcase (even though they are relatively insecure) and keeping it **on my person at all times.** Then, instead of ordering the HoS to protect the disk, order him to protect you. Ideally get a detachment of redshirts to act as your personal bodyguard at all times. You can then either wall yourself into the armoury if you're paranoid, or stride proudly through the station with your new armed guards.

This helps keep both you and the disk safe, and it gives both sides a fun chance at success (and a chance to roleplay more, if that's what you're in to).

Comment: I like this answer, but it does make you a HUGE target.  Especially since the Armory tends to be a high priority target for the nuke ops in the first place.  Keeping mobile seems more wise.

Comment: Its true - personally I find that being a target makes the round more interesting for me (and hopefully everyone else). But it's partly down to personal preference as well

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with a briefcase, shit can get emagged open and it will, not worth the clumsyness. If you want to be REALLY secure and REALLY slow down the syndicate, put it in the AI core.

In general it's better to keep the disk on your person at all times, but if you're doing that, don't take unnecessary risks, the disk is more important than anyone else's life.